# print drupal field_view_field value only

Tags: drupal, printing, field, render

I'm using the code below to print the out the field of nodes to specific areas and it works great. But theres an instance where I just want to print the value you of field without the label. Seems as it should be pretty easy but I'm having a bit of trouble. I'd appreciate any help as i'm pretty new to drupal. Thanks

```
<?php 
  print drupal_render(field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_description')); ?>
```

Answer (score 28, accepted):

`field_view_value()` takes a `$display` argument that you can use to hide the label:

```
$display = array('label' => 'hidden');
$view = field_view_field('node', $node, 'field_description', $display);
print drupal_render($view);
```

If you just want to extract the raw value of the field you can use [`field_get_items()`](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!field!field.module/function/field_get_items/7) instead:

```
$items = field_get_items('node', $node, 'field_description');
$first_item = array_shift($items);
$description = $first_item['value'];
```

The column name (`$first_item['whatever']`) will depend on the type of field you're using. For text fields it will be `value`. Remember to sanitise the input with `check_plain()` before you output it as Drupal's convention is to store the raw input data and sanitise it upon output.

Comment: Thanks. Thats exactly what I asked for. But I am having an issue with what I'm trying to do. Im trying to print the value of the field in a link, like such href="whatever.com/<?php echo 'field value' ?>" Is there a way to print just the value of the field not wrapped in a div? Thanks Again

Comment: Yeah there's a different API function for that, I've updated the answer

Comment: How can I get only single value if there are more than on value using field_view_field()