# Drupal 7 & AddThis - Passing field values to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, drupal, drupal-7

I am running Drupal 7 and using AddThis for social sharing and having a problem figuring out how to pass a field value to JavaScript.

I want to override the standard AddThis twitter share language - which is the {{title}}{{url}} of the node. I think I know where and theoretically how to do this - but having some trouble implementing it as I am new to PHP and JS.

I have created a text field with a computer name **field_tweet**

I have added the following in my Drupal html.php template page:

```
<?php $tweet = $node->field_tweet['und'][0]['value']; ?>

<script type="text/javascript">
  var addthis_share = {

templates: {
twitter: '<?php print $tweet; ?>'}

}
</script>
```

Here is the AddThis documentation: http://support.addthis.com/customer/portal/articles/1337996-the-addthis_share-variable

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work. I was missing two big things:

1) I had to put the code in **node.tpl.php** instead of html.php.

2) I realized I needed to render JUST the value for the field without wrappers. I found that soultion here: [print drupal field_view_field value only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11694770/print-drupal-field-view-field-value-only)